# Need to find a solution for querying a database with a filed that may receive multiple values

Tags: c#, sql

I have been tasked to run a query that I am not too certain how to run.  I am using C# and SQL.  I will will need to run a query that will get me all the customers name and phone numbers where Balance equals 100 and 200 and 300 and 400.

Example of Table

[image]

I am using  using a string builder that will receive the SQL command.

For example:

```
     StringBuilder sqlCommandBuilderTxt = new StringBuilder();
                    sqlCommandBuilderTxt.Append("SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Phone#, Balance ");

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

    sqlCommandBuilderTxt.Append("Balance= @balance");

    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", "1"); << the logic will go here
```

Not sure how to implement the logic that will make my search for all the value balances which I want

Comment: Have you (can you) tried using an "IN" query? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I put together really quick, but on inspecting after the code runs, the command and parameters look correct.  As others have said an IN statement is your best bet, you just need to loop through the parameters to dynamically create the IN statement.

```
        //assumining the params are ints, this would be replaced with your values you want to filter with
        int[] paramValues = {100,200,300,500};

        StringBuilder sqlCommandBuilderTxt = new StringBuilder();
                sqlCommandBuilderTxt.Append("SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Phone#, Balance FROM tblname WHERE ");

        sqlCommandBuilderTxt.Append("Balance IN (");

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

        //loop through all the param values to build the IN statement and create the paramaters
        for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.Count(); i++)
        {
            sqlCommandBuilderTxt.Append("@balance"+i+",");
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance" + i, paramValues[i]);

            //remove trailing , and add end ) for IN statement
            if (i == paramValues.Count() - 1)
            {
                sqlCommandBuilderTxt.Remove(sqlCommandBuilderTxt.Length-1,1).Append(")");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to append "where" before placing conditions.
2. As CodingGorilla pointed out, you can use IN.

The query would then look like:

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, Phone, Balance FROM your_table_name WHERE balance in (100, 200, 300, 400)
```